# troubleshooting: Network unclaimed -> Wifi Adapter not working

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04

I just bought a Dell optiplex SFF machine with Ubuntu Linux 18.4 preinstalled. Through a misconfiguration from my side, the machine was shipped with two Network cards without Wifi capabilities. So I bought the:*ASUS WLAN-AX PCIe Adapter PCE-AX3000 with Bluetooth 5.0* , replaced the extra non-Wifi card with the above and tried to get it up running but didn't succeed up to now.

I went through many articles but couldn't get the card up running and as I am quite new to linux I don't know what else to check. I was hoping that someone knows what to do in order to have it working.

I provided below some outputs that I thought could be helpful.

The UNCLAIMED Network adapter is the one that is making troubles.

```
lshw -c network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a4200000-a4203fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno1
       version: 10
       serial: c8:f7:50:f7:a7:a3
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.5-4 ip=192.168.100.115 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:138 memory:a4400000-a441ffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

The first one is the driver that the wifi card came with on a separate CD-ROM and as it is already in the firmware folder I assume it has been properly installed.

```
(base) bdw@DELL-bdw:/lib/firmware$ ls | grep iwlwifi-cc
iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode
```

kernel

```
(base) bdw@DELL-bdw:/$ uname -a
Linux DELL-bdw 4.15.0-1073-oem #83-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 17 11:21:18 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` We suspect that your very new wireless card is not yet supported in kernel version 4.15-xx. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading kernel to 5.3 should fix the issue

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

But OEM drivers if any may not build.

Comment: Upgrading the kernel solved the issue.  **@Pilot6**Thanks a lot for the advice.